# ¿Por qué se le dice "vencimiento" a la caducidad?

Tags: etimología

"Vencer" con el significado de "caducar" (o sea "llegar a una fecha límite" un alimento o un contrato) es muy usado y seguramente lo recoge el diccionario. ¿Tiene alguna relación con el otro "vencer" (el que significa "triunfar")?

Comment: Lo veo así: dando la acepción de *vencer* que expones, se usa así porque cuando llegue el punto dado, el producto será *derrotado* en cierta forma. En otras palabras, después de la fecha límite, [algo] venció al producto.

Comment: Efectivamente, el DRAE lleva en [vencer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bW2GDZD) _11. intr. Dicho de un término o de un plazo: Cumplirse_. A mí me da la sensación de que hay cierta sucesión de palabras que pueden llevar de una a otra: vencer, ganar, superar, cumplir.

Comment: Agregando a lo que dice @fe, ya en latín el verbo [vincere](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dvinco) tenía algunas connotaciones afines: _derretirse_ la nieve (en pasivo: ser vencida) en el sentido de cambiar de estado, y por otro lado _sobrevivir_ o _superar_ un período de tiempo.

Answer (score 1):

Es un sinónimo. (En este caso concreto)

La caducidad no es otra cosa que la derrota de un producto en su lucha contra el tiempo, y esa es la definición de la primera acepción de vencimiento.

Comment: El tiempo es el que vence, no el producto. Entonces debería ser "fecha de derrota".

Comment: No importa quien es el vencedor o el vencido, la fecha de vencimiento es la misma. Se habla del hecho, no del causante.